# htaccess RewriteRule for found id in middle of url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need get objectid from seo url e.g When I use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^company/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /lt?openobjectid=$1
```

evrything is ok when I use `example.com/company/12` but if use `example.com/company/12/some-text` I get server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your regex pattern is not matching `example.com/company/12/some-text`.

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^company/([a-z0-9-]+)(?:/.*)?$ lt?openobjectid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: `A-Za-z` is redundant with `NC` flag there :)